# Solidity contract for supply chain

Tags: function, solidity

I am new to smart contracts and have been developing a mini blockchain based supply chain management system. I have seen a tutorial that shows a transaction between two accounts. I want to implement a contract that can show a the transaction but among various parties. Pretending they transfer money in-between them
Example: A=>B=>C=>D
I want to show the flow of the money among all the accounts.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that you are expecting the `from` to be `A` and `to` to be `D`? At the same time, keeping `B` and `C` in the record?

Comment: yes i am. please show or refer me to an exercise that can help, thank you

Comment: Image we have a product x. Product x will be passed by A=>B, the B=>C and then C=>D, i want to see the entire transaction exchange from A to D